# Error: Either the report chart definition changed, the running user has no access to some fields, or the table has no numeric column.

Tags: dashboard

I am getting below error while adding report to dashboard.
I am adding as system admin

```
Error: Either the report chart definition changed, the running user has no access to some fields, or the table has no numeric column.
```

Comment: I got the answer shortly https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_select_running_user.htm&language=en..Thanks All

Answer (score 2):

I've recently run into this issue and while there are some somewhat obvious causes (permissions, a field that was previously summarized but now isn't), they were not what was causing my issue.

The scenario for me was a dashboard with a table component that had been running for a very long time.  One of users went in and changed one of the grouping fields in the source report.  There were 3 groupings on the report but only one was used in the Dashboard.  When she received this error, she changed it back.  Only the error didn't go away.  What we uncovered is that apparently the Dashboard cares about the order in which the grouping for an underlying report is created.  I imagine the reason to be that the order in which groupings are placed on a report is how Salesforce determines the order in which to summarize the multiple levels of grouping.  I believe in this case, Salesforce perceived that we were trying to "skip" a level.

We made several trials to determine that this indeed was the cause.  We removed all groupings and then put them back in different orders.  Whichever was the first grouping we added (and saved) was the one that showed up as Column 1 when customizing the table.  We could not select Group 2 or Group 3 until subsequent columns.

By going back and removing the groupings and placing them in the order in which we wanted them to appear, we resolved the issue.  Once the underlying report was built in this order, we removed the source from the table component on the Dashboard and added it back.